# Cannot read time_stamp with type `strfmt.DateTime` from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go, timestamp

I'm trying to write timestamp with `strfmt.DateTime` type (https://godoc.org/github.com/go-openapi/strfmt#DateTime) into the mongodb

I can successfully write this format of date into the DB, which looks like this:

> { "_id" : ObjectId("5bcb58f7540ac6d0bc946e22"), "status" : "test", "time_stamp" : {
>   "data" : "2018-10-21T00:33:59.699+08:00" } }

But I just can't retrieve it from the mongodb, the value of the time_stamp always shows `0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`, I just don't see why.

Here is my code, any suggestions or opinions are welcome! Thanks

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/go-openapi/strfmt"
    "github.com/op/go-logging"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type TxStatus struct {
    Status    string           `json:"status" bson:"status"`
    TimeStamp *strfmt.DateTime `json:"time_stamp" bson:"time_stamp"`
}

type MongoDBOperations struct {
    mongoSession *mgo.Session
    database     string
    collection   string
}

var log = logging.MustGetLogger("example")

func main() {
    mo := MongoDBOperations{}
    mo.database = Database
    mo.collection = Collection

    // We need this object to establish a session to our MongoDB.
    mongoDBDialInfo := &mgo.DialInfo{
        Addrs:    []string{MongoDBHosts},
        Timeout:  60 * time.Second,
        Database: AuthDatabase,
        Username: AuthUserName,
        Password: AuthPassword,
    }

    // Create a session which maintains a pool of socket connections
    // to our MongoDB.
    var err error
    mo.mongoSession, err = mgo.DialWithInfo(mongoDBDialInfo)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("CreateSession: %s\n", err)
    }

    mo.mongoSession.SetMode(mgo.Eventual, true)
    write(mo)
    read(mo)

}

func write(mo MongoDBOperations) {
    log.Info("write operation")

    session := mo.mongoSession.Copy()
    defer session.Close()
    c := session.DB(Database).C(Collection)

    timestamp := strfmt.DateTime(time.Now())

    txStatus := TxStatus{
        Status:    "test",
        TimeStamp: &timestamp,
    }

    if err2 := c.Insert(txStatus); err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }
}

func read(mo MongoDBOperations) {
    log.Info("write operation")

    session := mo.mongoSession.Copy()
    defer session.Close()
    c := session.DB(Database).C(Collection)

    // Find and Count
    var status []TxStatus
    err2 := c.Find(bson.M{"status": "test"}).All(&status)
    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }
    for _, elem := range status {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", elem)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dug through the code of `github.com/go-openapi/strfmt` and what I've found out is that they are using `github.com/globalsign/mgo` instead of `gopkg.in/mgo.v2`. Changing imports to use `github.com/globalsign/mgo` and `github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson` has fixed the issue. Globalsign package is fork of `mgo.v2` so the methods remain the same and there is no need to change any code besides import.

Comment: Same issue with the latest version of the library, but now they're using the official Mongodb driver and it's not as simple as changing the imports :(